# Grafana - how to provision Cloudwatch datasource with custom namespaces?

Tags: grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, provisioning

I would like to automate the creation of my Grafana dashboards. For some resources, we use AWS Cloudwatch as the datasource. We use custom namespaces to provide additional metrics.

I know how to provision datasources, but the problem with Cloudwatch is that there is no possibility to store custom namespaces info in .yaml file.

Maybe someone here has some workaround for that? With AWS CLI it is easy to get the list of Namespaces, but how to provide this data into Grafana configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `customMetricsNamespaces` in `jsonData` block.

```
  - name: cloudwatch
    type: cloudwatch
    jsonData:
      authType: credentials
      defaultRegion: eu-west-1
      customMetricsNamespaces: ns1/ns1,ns2/ns2
    isDefault: true
    editable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.5/features/datasources/cloudwatch/ for the configurations.

Kindly use customMetricsNameSpace which will help you identify to pull the custom metrics data.

```
- name: CloudWatch_Test
  type: cloudwatch
  jsonData:
    authType: keys
    defaultRegion: us-east-1
    customMetricsNamespaces: <>
  secureJsonData:
    accessKey: <>
    secretKey: <>
  editable: true #If you would like to edit your data post configuration.
```

Hopefully this helps you.